# Select stored procedure results into tables

Tags: sql-server

I have stored procedure which returns multiple data sets and I need to create tables based on that data sets to get data types. Found this code

```
SELECT *    
INTO newTable
FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
'EXEC ISS.dbo.sp')
```

but it works only for first result set and I need tables for all results

Comment: Whether all the result sets are of same structure

Comment: No, they have different data and different number of columns

Comment: I know it can be done in ADO.net, but as far as I'm aware, there is not a way. Any chance you can refactor the SP into separate calls? One thought is to create as many SPs as you have datasets, and if the main sp really needs to return all datasets, just call each sub SP in sequence.

Comment: Can you give the structure of your data sets?

Comment: Perhaps can you find ideas in this page: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: I don't have permission to change procedure (even to see it content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, cleaner way of using stored procedure output to populate data to a table is a much required solution. There are many ways including the ones you have shown above, but every technique has its own plus and minus.

The solution I have used is create global temporary table

I don't know if it suits for our need.

Answer (score 0):

Once OpenTable is created you can do this over and over again:

```
Insert into OpenTable
Exec dbo.proc55
```